# how to make conditional ggplot geoms

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Jack", "Jill", "John"),
                  Qty =  c(3, 8, 4), 
                  Violation = c("F", "T", "F"))

ggplot(df1, aes(Name, Qty, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5), linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_point(data = df1 %>% filter(Violation == "T"), color = "red")
```

[image: ggplot conditional highlight]

The code above highlights any data point meeting the `Violation == "T"` criteria. However, my data frames change, and sometimes don't contain any data points meeting `Violation == "T"`. When this happens I get an error, like below:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Jack", "Jill", "John"),
                  Qty =  c(3, 2, 4), 
                  Violation = c("F", "F", "F"))

ggplot(df2, aes(Name, Qty, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5), linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_point(data = df2 %>% filter(Violation == "T"), color = "red")

#> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y
```

Do I need to construct some type of `ifelse()` statement to make my ggplot code work whether there are any `Violation == "T"` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply color the dots directly by factor level. By making 'F' black and 'T' red you can get the same effect.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(Name, Qty, group=1)) + 
     geom_line() +
     geom_point(aes(col=Violation)) + 
     geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5), linetype = "dashed")+
     scale_color_manual(values=c('black','red'))
```

Comment: In `geom_point(aes(col = Violation))` is `col` shorthand for color or is it the base R column indexes function?

Comment: Yes, in ggplot2, `col` can be used for the color aesthetic in place of `color` or `colour`

Comment: This answer will handle more than 2 levels of "Violation" if you define the function `ff <- function(x){ifelse(x == "T", "red", "black")}`, create a named vector with `cols<-ff(df2$Violation)` and then `names(cols)<-df2$Violation` and then change the last line to `scale_colour_manual(values=c(cols))`